# Text representation of Google Home response

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Is there a way to capture (if it's not already stored) text search responses that Google Home receives before 'speaking' them out?

For example:

```
Me: When was Diego Velázquez born?
Google Home: Diego Rodríguez de Silva y Velázquez was born in 1599
```

I would like to capture that text string (`Diego Rodríguez de Silva y Velázquez was born in 1599`).

Is this possible in any way by putting Google Home into some sort of dev mode?

I was specifically interested in doing this on Google Home (rather than just Google Voice) as I've heard that the search results may differ.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no programmatic way using Actions on Google. You can see all of your activity with the Google Assistant on [your activity page](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?product=31).

If you were to use the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/), you could receive an audio response from the Google Assistant, but it would not get you the text output as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Using the Google Assistant SDK wouldn't give the _exact_ response that Google Home would give though(?) – I've heard that Google Assistant's responses sometimes differ to those of the Google Home device.

Comment: Yes there's a few cases that are slightly different. The SDK doesn't do phone calls, media playback, and may answer a few things differently, but for most use cases, weather, time, personal results, it should be the same.

Comment: Interesting! Do you know if Google search results would be the same?

Comment: I've followed up with the Google Assistant team on this, and the SDK is apparently only for creating custom actions – It can't be used for interacting with in-built ones.

Comment: There's a difference between 'Actions on Google' and the 'Google Assistant SDK'.

Answer (score 0):

Only get info of your activities on google... if only your request is possible though...